# BottomNavigationView Disabling the grey box when clicking on an item

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

How do I disable that greybox that appears when you click/hold on a bottomnavigation menu item?

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:itemIconSize="26dp"/>
```

Comment: Try setting `app:itemBackground=@null`. Or a custom selector ..

Comment: @ADM Perfect, type your answer below so I can mark it correct!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable or change the selector by using `app:itemBackground` attribute.
Use `@null` to disable it or use a custom selector drawable to change it (Do remember to create a drawable according to api version drawable, drawable-v21, drawable -v24 if you want that ripple effect).

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    app:itemBackground="@null"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
    app:itemIconSize="26dp"/>
```